# Filtering array elements with # in them not working

Tags: ruby

Edited: I were thrying to get IRC channels names from the huge string:

https://www.filesharing.com/download/iOccqjTzk17oAKk1wZ2M
(It's too huge to paste in)

I were trying to make a list with ONLY elements that starts with a #. And I wrote a script to make an array out of string, so I can use for i loop and destroy the elements that doesn't starts with #. But it didn't work and my script returned an answer like that:

```
Emacs:
Org
(Sep
Release
https://orgmode.org/Changes.html
227
148
#reprap
anything
printers,
why
here.
printing.
Beginners
What
build?
http://reprap.org/wiki/Prusa_i3
Remember:
https://xkcd.com/1357/
<gthx>
something
something
149
#videolan
multimedia
source!
VLC
iOS:
3.5.3
cone!
#wikimedia-operations
(see
https://www.wikimediastatus.net/)
Log:
https://w.wiki/6ah
https://wm-bot.wmcloud.org/logs/%23wikimedia-operations/
Clinic
topranks
call:
jhathaway)
```

Here's my code:

```
class ListStripper

  def self.striplist(list)
    list = list.split " " # Making a list out of string

    for i in list do
      if i[0] != "#" # Checking if elements DO NOT starts with # so we can delete it.
        list.delete(i) # Deliting the useless elements.

      end

    end

    return list # Returning the list

  end

end
```

I tried to change the input data, and it still didn't worked. So now Im trying to ask for help here and don't get roasted for my shit code.

Comment: I've already provided an answer below. However, here are some tips for writing a better question on StackOverflow:

Comment: 1. Try to provide a [mcve]. Your question is not minimal (did you really need such a huge input to explain the problem?), and it's not complete (I can't just copy+paste your code to run it. There is extra code needed that you haven't provided, and I'd need to write myself). Your example isn't *bad*, but there's significant room for improvement.

Comment: 2. Try to use accurate terms. You post title says "Sorting", but this question has nothing to do with sorting. It's about *filtering*.

Comment: 3. Try to format your code elegantly. Messy whitespace (did you really need so many blank lines?) and comments (e.g. did you really need to put `return list # Returning the list`) just adds noise.

Comment: 4. Try to keep your question on-point. Writing *"Im trying to ask for help here and don't get roasted for my shit code."* isn't constructive. We know there are people of all backgrounds and abilities here, and we try to be a helpful/collaborative community. There are loads of valuable questions here written by absolute beginners, and that's a good thing!

Comment: Your input data looks like it already has been processed. How does the original data look like? And why do you want "elements" starting with `#`? Are you trying to extract hashtags from a text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the unique things about Ruby is there's often extremely minimal, yet still understandable solution to problems like this:

```
list.grep(/\A#/)
```

Where that involves a small regular expression that means `#` character anchored to the *start of string* (`\A`).

In Ruby you'll often never use `for`, which might seem strange, but `x.each do |y|` is usually better than `for y in x`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is that you are removing from the list while iterating over it. I tried to store the data to be deleted in a separate array and delete them later in a second loop and it was OK.

However the correct approach is to use `select` method.

```rb
  def striplist(list)
    list = list.split(" ")
    list.select{|element| element.start_with? '#'}
  end
```

Also for your future loops, it is more common in Ruby to use `each` instead of `for in`. You can use it for all `Enumerable` objects like `Array`, `Hash` or `Range`. I don't think I have ever used keyword `for` in Ruby.

```rb
  list.each do |i|
    # do whatever you want with i
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is only half-working because you are **mutating the array whilst iterating over it**. This causes some unexpected results, because the `for` loop isn't smart enough to correctly loop over all items in an array that's *changing mid-loop*.

Here's a simplification of your code (written in a way you can just copy+paste to run it yourself), with some extra debug output:

```
list = ['delete-me', 'delete-me-too', '#keep-me', '#keep-me-too']
for i in list do
  puts "DEBUG: Checking element: #{i}"
  if i[0] != "#"
    list.delete(i)
  end
  puts "DEBUG: Current list: #{list}"
end

puts "Final result: #{list}"
```

And here is the output:

```
DEBUG: Checking element: delete-me
DEBUG: Current list: ["delete-me-too", "#keep-me", "#keep-me-too"]
DEBUG: Checking element: #keep-me
DEBUG: Current list: ["delete-me-too", "#keep-me", "#keep-me-too"]
DEBUG: Checking element: #keep-me-too
DEBUG: Current list: ["delete-me-too", "#keep-me", "#keep-me-too"]
Final result: ["delete-me-too", "#keep-me", "#keep-me-too"]
```

Note that **`"delete-me-too"` was never iterated over**. That's because on the second loop, the array has changed shape - i.e. the "second element" has shifted position to be the "first element".

---

There are several ways to fix this, but the easiest is to follow more ruby-convention, and write your code in a "ruby way". Your current code looks like that of a JavaScript/Python developer who has directly translated the syntax into ruby.

I'd suggest writing it like this:

```
list.select{ |element| element.start_with? '#' }
```

The key difference here (aside from being much less code!) is that you're *building a new array*, instead of *mutating the original array*.